# How to access node js post method from angularjs to redirect to another page?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, post

I have my redirect code inside nodejs post method.,

```
       app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
         res.render(__dirname + "/views/registration.html" ,{mob:mob}); 

         }
```

In html I am using angularjs,

```
   return $http.post('/login',{data }).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);

     });
```

currently request is going inside post method. but page redirection is not happening. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: mob is not defined.

Comment: There is no "page redirection"?

Comment: @RahulSharma thanks.But I am passing mob value inside data & retrieving it in server side. So that is not the problem.

Comment: why you want to redirect from the server you can do that from client side also.

Comment: @RahulSharma while redirecting,I want to pass some parameter also. Is that possible in angularjs?

Comment: It's possible in angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to redirect a page using a post request, but redirecting a post request should just cause the client to make the request again to the redirect address returned - it doesn't affect the page making the request, because the request is being made by AJAX, not as part of a page load.

That said, you aren't actually redirecting: `res.render` is not a real redirect response.  You're effectively rendering a different page at the original url.

A redirect response - if that's really what you intended, is done by return a status 301 or 302 (temporary and permanent redirects) and can be achieved in using `res.redirect(URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO)`.  *I don't think this is what you meant to do, though.*

More to the point though, a post request redirect may not be useful to you, because the post request in your code will receive as response the output of rendering the login page.  Given that this is an AJAX request, you need to handle the need for a redirect somehow yourself, something like this:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        redirectTo: 'URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO'
    })
});
```

Then in client side:

```
$http.post('/login', { data }).success((data) => {
    if (data.redirectTo) {
        // Code to redirect to page.  Window.location.href = data.redirectTo or something less clumsy
    }
})
```

It's worth noting though, that this isn't necessarily the best way to do this, it's just a way to achieve URL redirects with the response to a post request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried like you said. But I am getting data.redirectTo value as "undefined". Can you help me? @Owen C. Jones

Comment: See what the data value is, it may be that you need to parse the JSON

Comment: thanks. it is redirecting now. is it possible to send a parameter along with it while redirecting? @–Owen C. Jones

Comment: @sasi, sure add it the the res.json, and it will become part of the parsed object.  I should stress though that this is a bit of a weird way to do this, you should maybe investigate whether there are better conventions for it in the specific tech you're using.